# Configuring Keycloak as a middleman for authentication between AWS SSO and Azure IDP

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, keycloak

I am currently working from a container and need to authenticate with AWS services. However, the authentication process requires going through AWS SSO, which redirects me to our Azure IDP for authentication. To streamline this process and avoid entering my credentials each time, I want to leverage Keycloak as a middleman for authentication.

Can someone please explain the necessary configuration steps to set up Keycloak to handle this authentication flow? My goal is to have the Keycloak server handle the authentication process and return a token back to my container, enabling seamless authentication with AWS services.

Any guidance or insights on the configuration requirements, including Keycloak settings, AWS SSO setup, and container integration, would be greatly appreciated.

PS. Please keep in mind that adding an enterprise application into Azure AD and configuring an IDP is not an option for me. I simply want it to handle my auth with Azure.